# Firestore Swift Network Detection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to include a banner in my app to alert users when they lose connection to Firebase. I don't need this written into the database, I just need to alert clients locally. RDTD seems to include presence detection that publishes this data to GC, but I don't need something that advanced.

I simply want to trigger a local function when the connection to Firebase changes. How can I do this?